# Populating the $variables['classes-array'] in preprocess_html function

Tags: theming

It seems most likely that the following code is not working due to bad php but I just can't understand why. If I var_dump `$variables['classes']` it returns that it is an array with the classes listed in it beautifully.

I debugged the `$item` and returns very nicely what I want as well. Then why don't these things get added to my `$variables['classes-array'];`?

```
    <?php

function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    dsm($variables);
    $path = url($_GET['q']);
    dsm(var_dump($variables['classes_array']));
    $path_items = explode('/', $path);
    foreach ($path_items as $item) {
        array_push($variables['classes_array'], $item);
    }
}
```

also tried `array_push($variables['classes_array'][], $item);`

Comment: Just a note, I think the Devel module suggests you use `dpm` over `dsm` at this point in time.

Comment: Also when you're running `dsm` you're outputting the `$variables` array *before* you've made changes to it.

Comment: Yes exactly that was the problem :s. I kept checking the dsm output instead of looking at the html. There classes where in the html the whole time. I lost enough time on this to hopefully learn to never do it again

Comment: Lesson well learned :)  Trust me, we've all learned it, and forget it from time to time.

Comment: It's reassuring to hear that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by putting the debug code *after* the change of values have taken place in the code.

Comment: Ajit I think the problem was perceptual because the value was probably being added to the array, but since he visually output the array before he added the variable, he perceived that the value was not being added to the array, when in fact it was, and he says as much.